# ошибка в ubuntu git: зависит: liberror-perl но он не может быть установлен

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git

На виртуальной машине Hyper-V произведена установка ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. После установки произведена попытка установить git:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

В результате ошибка: git: зависит: liberror-perl но он не может быть установлен

В инете советуют сделать:

```
 sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Не помогло. Что делать?
Можно конеш, переустановить линукс... но может можно проще?

Что ещё опробовано:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    ==> /etc/apt/sources.list <==
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20190227)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
head: невозможно открыть '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*' для чтения: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

Comment: небось [бардак](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1021819/178576) в списке источников.

Comment: sudo atp-get autoremove
    sudo apt-get autoclean
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
    sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: @zalex, `;` или `&&` забыл.

Comment: @donRumata почему забыл ? Не писал попросту.

Comment: А что-то другое, кроме *git* пытались установить? Покажите вывод команды 
*cat /etc/apt/sources.list*. Я поддерживаю мнение aleksandr barakin. Ну и самый тупой вопрос: из Вашей ВМ интернет доступен?

Comment: @zalex, ну т.е. камент нельзя просто скопировать - его ещё и дорабатывать надо. Такое себе.

Comment: @donRumata  отчего же. Я вот смог. Вы тоже попробуйте.

Comment: @zalex, ок. Пойдём ещё чуть дальше. Зачем писать `sudo`? И так же понятно и можно дописать самостоятельно.

Comment: @donRumata мусье, за ким чертом вообще нужно отвечать если можно не отвечать, правда ?  А так же еще можно не лезть с советами во все щели. Хорошего вам дня. До свидания.

Comment: Инет грузит - mail.ru. НО почту так и не удалось загрузить, дико тормозит и не дает ввести логин и пароль...

Comment: @Sergey
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
Ответ: нет такого файла или каталога

Comment: @Sergey Кроме git ничего не ставилось, не пробовалось.

Comment: @zalex, на самом деле удобнее, если можно просто скопировать и использовать... а то новички, типа меня не владеют данным синтаксисом. Я не ворчу! И благодарю за советы.

Comment: @zalex, за ким чертом вообще нужно советовать неполные советы, если можно не советовать, правда? А так же ещё можно не лезть с указаниями на не лезть с советами во все щели. И вам хорошего дня. До свидания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё-таки заработало! Git установлен. Вероятно, помогло sudo apt-get autoclean... единственная команда, которая завершилась успехом...

Comment: Раз помогло - отметь ответ галочкой.

Comment: @don Rumata, так он в комментариях к вопросу, как его отметить?

Comment: Не. Ты ж сам щас ответил как поехало. Отметь этот ответ галкой ну и если хочешь указать конкретный камент - отредактируй ответ.

Answer (score 1):

> cat /etc/apt/sources.list Ответ: нет такого файла или каталога

это означает, что система управления пакетами у вас НЕ настроена. Подозреваю,  потому, что из вашей ВМ нет доступа в иНет. Попробуте, работая в виртуалке, выполнить команду

```
ping google.com
```

Если пропингуется, то значит сеть есть, просто в системе управления пакетами не задано ни одного репозитария. Тогда сходите вот сюда:

```
https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9
```

прочитайте инструкции и задайте стандартные репозитарии. Всё просто :-)

Если же сети нет - то зайдите в настройку вашей ВМ, найдите там пункт про доступ к сети изнутри ВМ (в разных ВМ этот пункт может называться по разному) и включите галку.  Тоже - всё просто :-)

Comment: Получилось пропинговать с 3-ей попытки... сеть есть однозначно - так как письмо удалось отправить на mail.ru.  Но очень медленно работает...

Comment: @Jane_Brown - *сеть есть однозначно* - отлично! Теперь на панели задач (слева) нажимете шестерёнку, далее - "Программы и обновления", переходите на закладку "Программное обеспечение Ubuntu" и настраиваете там всё, в соответствии с инструкцией и Вашими предпочтениями.